# Deterministic vs. Non-Deterministic PDA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

The following is an example of language $a^nb^n$ where $n \geq 1$

[image]

From what I have heard that in *finite state machines* if you see epsilon moves, then it is NFA otherwise it is DFA. But in this case, the definition was: "If a PDA has more than one paths going accept state then it is non-deterministic PDA" but what about epsilons?

So, Is this an example of Non-deterministic or Deterministic PDA? How to recognize NPDAs from DPDAs? Can I create both NPDA and DPDA for this language as above?

Comment: What's your source? What they define as non-determinism I know as ambiguity. Non-deterministic automata can be unambiguous! Also, the definition for NFA is definitely not correct. Please cite your source, and make sure you represent it correctly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition is wrong. A PDA is non-deterministic if in some state there are several possible transitions. It doesn't matter if that applies to a transition to a final state.

Your example is deterministic. Check:

- From state $q_0$ with $Z_0$ on the stack, on reading $a$ there is one possibility. In the same case there is no alternative on input $\epsilon$
- Similarly, from $q_0$ with stack $a$, only one option. No $\epsilon$ alternative
- In $q_0$, with $a$ on the stack and inputs $a$ and $b$, again one move only. No $\epsilon$ alternative

You can complete the analysis for the other possible combinations of state, stack symbol, an possible input, making sure there is one option for a given input symbol, and if $\epsilon$ input is allowed, no "real" symbol alternative is available (e.g. in $q_1$ with $Z_0$ on the stack, only $\epsilon$ can be read).